# Assigning labels and creating sorted lists in matlab?

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

I lack experience in matlab, & have a problem writing a code for a program that starts as follows:

```
N = input('Enter N:');     % The number of rows (say 6)
M = input('Enter M:');     % The number of columns (say 4)
Mat1 = round(rand(N,M));   % Creating a random binary matrix
B = sum(Mat1);           % Calculating the sum of the elements of the columns
Mat2 = sort(B,'descend')   % Sorting the elements in a descending order
```

What I have to do is as follows:

1- Mat1 must have its rows and columns assigned to look like this:

```
   C1 C2 C3 C4
N1  0  1  1  1
N2  0  0  1  1
N3  0  1  1  0
N4  0  1  0  1
N5  1  1  0  1
N6  1  0  0  1
```

2- Mat2 should display the assigned labels of the columns instead of the sum values to be like:

```
Mat2 = [C4 C2 C3 C1]    % The labels of the columns
```

in addition to

```
Mat2 = [5 4 3 2]    % The sorting of the columns in a descending order
```

3- Mat1 must be divided into 2XN subsets; for example:

```
   C1 C2 C3 C4
N1  0  1  1  1
N2  0  0  1  1
```

4- Out of each subset, make a list which contains the columns that have only **1** in it, such as:

```
N1N2 = [C3 C4]   % Ascending sorting is done according to the values of Mat2
```

Hope the explanation is clear enough. Thank you for any sort of help you might be able to provide.

Comment: First off, replace `B = sum('Mat1');` by `B = sum(Mat1);`

Comment: Also, last line should probably be `[~, Mat2] = sort(B,'descend')` (I think you want _second_ output of `sort`)

Comment: Thanks for the notification Luis. Fixed now